# undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass in Exibe the mail of table Father

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a problem, i make this atribbuition i comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
```

and this in user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
```

but this dont works:

```
  <% post.comments.each do |comment|   %>
    <div id="comments" >
      <%= comment.user.email %>
           <%= comment.comment %>
    </div>
   <%end%>
```

appear the error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

please what is the problem, in the create of the comment i make the atribbuition so , look:

```
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment],:user_id => current_user.id)
```

how i solve this error, please-

UPDATE NEXT RESPONSES, THE ERROR PERSISTES:

I try this:

```
@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user
@comment.post = @post
@comment.save
```

this

```
@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
```

and this:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user
@comment.save
```

dont works

same error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #48):

45: 
46:       <% post.comments.each do |comment|   %>
47:         <div id="comments" >
48:           <%= comment.user.email %>
49:                <%= comment.comment %>
50:         </div>
51:        <%end%>
```

i dont know what is wrong my model comment have :user_id

```
  attr_accessible :comment,:user_id,:post_id
```

and my form make is this

```
   <div id="comment_form_<%= post.id %>" style="display: none;" >

      <%= form_for [post,post.comments.build], :remote => true,:class=>"comment" do |com| %>
          <%= com.text_area :comment %>
          <%= com.submit "aaa" %>

      <%end %>
```

please help me i dont know where is the error, the db is migrate correctly

Comment: can you show db/schema.rb file ?

Comment: my schema.rb is:  ` create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "user_id"
  end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Model
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment, :user_id
end

#Controller
@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
```

But next would be better (:user_id is not accessible for mass-assignment):

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user
@comment.save
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the log you will probably see a warning about trying to assign user_id.  If you are going to use attr_accessible then you need to add all the attributes that you wish to assign.  Change

```
  attr_accessible :comment
```

to

```
  attr_accessible :comment,:user_id
```

Comment: @overallduka you have created many comment records where user is nil. So, clean up db table and try again.

Comment: Thanks but not is this , i reset the bd , create the post but when make comment dont appear "undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
" the same error =/

Comment: create(params[:comment].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user
@comment.post = @post
@comment.save
```