# undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass in Model Associations Rails, dont works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a problem, i make this atribbuition i comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
```

and this in user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
```

but this dont works:

```
  <% post.comments.each do |comment|   %>
    <div id="comments" >
      <%= comment.user.email %>
           <%= comment.comment %>
    </div>
   <%end%>
```

appear the error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

please what is the problem, in the create of the comment i make the atribbuition so , look:

```
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment],:user_id => current_user.id)
```

how i solve this error, please-

I try this:

```
@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user
@comment.post = @post
@comment.save
this

@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
```

and this:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user
@comment.save
```

dont works

same error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #48):

45: 
46:       <% post.comments.each do |comment|   %>
47:         <div id="comments" >
48:           <%= comment.user.email %>
49:                <%= comment.comment %>
50:         </div>
51:        <%end%>
```

i dont know what is wrong my model comment have :user_id

attr_accessible :comment,:user_id,:post_id

and my form make is this

```
   <div id="comment_form_<%= post.id %>" style="display: none;" >

      <%= form_for [post,post.comments.build], :remote => true,:class=>"comment" do |com| %>
          <%= com.text_area :comment %>
          <%= com.submit "aaa" %>

      <%end %>
```

please help me i dont know where is the error, the db is migrate correctly

UPDATE:

Have a before_filter and need login to see the page to comment, so have current_user, and i reset the bd and make new comments logged, i test meet getting the comment.user_id and get the id of the user but the method comment.user.email dont works, i will post the , the comment model is:

```
 attr_accessible :comment,:user_id,:post_id
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :comment ,:on =>:create
```

the model user is:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:username
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments



  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
```

Comment: Do not post same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175913/undefined-method-email-for-nilnilclass-in-exibe-the-mail-of-table-father

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be using `@post` instead of `post` in view file will help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure, that current_user is *not nil* at the moment you save the **comment**.
And there is no comments without user at the moment you list **post.comments**.

That is all you have to. If it doesn't work again - show us the full source code of actions and models.

Comment: I have UPDATE the post whit this informations please check.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the database comments table that it should store user_id. If any of records of @post.comments not have user_id in it then it throws the error. May be one or more record cantain nil in user_id column.

use `select * from comments where user_id is null;`